# Minimum switching load of a relay

Tags: power, relay, power-electronics

I was going through the datasheet and encountered the specification for minimum switching load of 100mA at 5VDC. What does this mean?

I need to switch a load of 1VDC and 20A. Is this relay suitable for my application?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> *I was going through the datasheet and encountered the specification for minimum switching load of 100mA at 5VDC. What does this mean?*

The specification 'Minimum switching load' relates to the reliability of contacts, affected by oxide / sulphide films, at low voltage / low current loads.

Here's the referred specification and the related footnote.

[image]
[image]

Here are the related FAQs

[image]

[image]

Here are the related links:

[*Panasonic Specifications*](https://mediap.industry.panasonic.eu/assets/download-files/import/mech_eng_hes.pdf) (Please refer page 3).

[*Panasonic FAQ 1*](https://ac-faq.industrial.panasonic.com/en/faq_detail.html?id=41348&category=&page=2)

[*Panasonic FAQ 2*](https://ac-faq.industrial.panasonic.com/en/faq_detail.html?id=1144)

> *I need to switch a load of 1VDC and 20A. Is this relay suitable for my application?*

Going by the relay specifications, its 'NO' contact (form A) is rated only for 5 A DC maximum (resistive) and its 'NC' contact (form B) only for 1 A DC maximum (resistive).

Hence the relay is not suitable for your application.

Answer (score 1):

> *I was going through the datasheet and encountered the specification for minimum switching load of 100mA at 5VDC. What does this mean?*

The 100 mA is called a [wetting current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetting_current) and, it's required to keep the relay contact surfaces free from oxidization (typically). The 5 volts is the minimum reliable open-circuit voltage to guarantee that the wetting current is passed when the contact closes.

> *I need to switch a load of 1VDC and 20A. Is this relay suitable for my
> application?*

Possibly not (based on the picture in your question). If in doubt, contact the supplier. I'd consider alternative methods like MOSFETs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If it is all about wetting current, 20A should be enough right?

Comment: @NELD unfortunately both voltage and current need to be exceeded so, your 1 volt supply won't meet the requirements because it doesn't equal or exceed 5 volts.

Comment: Thanks! I always thought that the term "current wetting" specifically refers to the flow of current through the contacts when they are closed, which can help to clean the contact surfaces and remove any non-conductive film.  Good to know that it also depends upon the voltage.